# Javascript conditional statement with a single pipe "|"

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Just wondering if anyone has come across this before.

I found in a project (that was handed over from another developer) a conditional statement that looked something like this:

```
if (variableOne == true | variable2 == true) {
    // Do something here
}
```

It didn't error, so seems to work. But, myself and a colleague have never seen an OR statement with a single pipe `|`, only 2 `||`.

Can anyone shed light on this mystery?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Its not an or statement it is bitwise math.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a bitwise OR operator.  It will first convert it into a 32 bit integer, then apply the bitwise OR operation to the two numbers that result.  In this instance, since `Boolean(1)` is true and `Number(true)` is 1, it will work fine without issue (the `==` operator will always return a boolean, and a if statement converts anything to a boolean).  Here are a few examples of how it works:

```
1 | 0; // 1
0 | 0; // 0
0 | 1; // 1
1 | 1; // 1
true | false; // 1
false | false; // 0
2 | 1; // 3 (00000010, 00000001) -> (00000011)
```

As both sides have to be converted to a number (and therefore evaluated), this may cause  unexpected results when using numbers when the logical OR statement (`||`) was meant to be used.  For this, take these examples:

```
var a = 1;
a | (a = 0);
console.log(a); // 0

var b = 1;
b || (b = 0);
console.log(b); // 1

// I wanted the first one
var c = 3 | 4; // oops, 7!
```

Reference: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10

Answer (score 2):

That's a bitwise OR, see the documentation from Mozilla: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_%28Bitwise_OR%29)

Answer (score 2):

The two pipes syntax "||" means it short circuits the logical expression. Evaluating only the needed until it knows the result.
What does it means?

```
if(a==null || a.type=='ok')
```

If a is null, it will evaluate only the first part of the expression, without errors on javascript side.

```
if(a==null | a.type=='ok')
```

If a is null in this case, you will have an error, since it will evaluate the second part of the expression too.

It's the same thing on others C type languages: Java, C,C++
And the same thing applies to '&' and '&&'

Comment: What Qantas said is also right, it is a bitwise operator. It behaves as I said, because with boolean expressions it will return 1 if it's true, 0 if it's false.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a bitwise OR, which in some very limited cases can substitute the `||`.

An important difference is that with `|` both operands are evaluated, unlike with the `||` which evaluates the second operand only if the first is false.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators